# how can I echo foreach iteration only once

Tags: php

Is it possible to `echo` the result of foreach only once? 
This is what I want to achieve:

```
18-sept-2016 | 08:00 AM | some text
               11:00 AM | some text
19-sept-2016 | 09:00 AM | some text
               09:10 AM | some text
               12:00 AM | some text
```

My code

```
<?php if (!empty($notification)): ?>
            <table class="table" id="notification_table">
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($notification as $row): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                <?php echo date('d M',strtotime($row['created_on'])) ?>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo date('h:m A', strtotime($row['created_on'])) ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row['notification_text'] ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    No notification
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
```

My current result :

```
18-sept-2016 | 08:00 AM | some text
18-sept-2016 | 11:00 AM | some text
19-sept-2016 | 09:00 AM | some text
19-sept-2016 | 09:10 AM | some text
19-sept-2016 | 12:00 AM | some text
```

I think it looks more efficient than my current result if I `echo` the date only once , but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Yes, You need to store the date first and every time check with new date if same then echo the empty otherwise echo the date.

Comment: can you show what is the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($notification);`?

Comment: actually you want to echo the date if it hasnt been echoed before, I would add it to an array and then check if its in there,  `$array[] = '18-sept-2016'` and `if( !in_array($array, '18-sept-2016') ) echo ...`

Comment: please show your input `$notification`

Comment: it just contains some text, like `driver is on your way` @Amani

Comment: Im curious, how do you get this output `18-sept-2016` from this `date('d M',strtotime($row['created_on']))` or am I missing something.

Comment: from controller, if you still curious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialize a varialble blank like `$is_same_date = ''`, I make the answer in the following manner cause your data is serialize.

Make a if condition to check your data is already printed or not, if it is in the `$is_same_date` then no need to show the date again, else you have to show the date and store your date to `$is_same_date`.

```
<?php 
$your_date = date('d M',strtotime($row['created_on']));
if($is_same_date != '' && $is_same_date == $your_date)
    echo '';
else{
    echo $your_date;
    $is_same_date = $your_date;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Like this:

```
    $dates = [];
    foreach ($notification as $row)

         $date = date('d M',strtotime($row['created_on']));
         if( !in_array($dates, $date ) ){
             echo $date;
             $dates[] = $date;
         }
      .....
   }
```

Check if a data is in the dates array, if not, echo and store it in the dates array for next time.

Comment: Why we need an extra array here?? we can do it using a temp variable, cause the date's are serialize.

Comment: Because if they are out of order then, it would make the same date again.  Not seeing the query or the source of the $row['created_on'], you cant be shure they will never be out of order.  I don't see how they are serialize.  if you mean in order, then Yea I suppose that works too.  It probably doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things.  If you want to talk performance wise, you'd do better to only format the date when its needed, rather then worry about a tiny array.

Comment: You are correct, but you did't mention in your answer properly. That's why i ask for... You must have to add these lines in your answer.

Comment: As I said, it's largely irrelevant, if they are out of order, because, think about what happens then....   You would get times from the wrong days, printed in the wrong place.  In that case it would be better to build an multi dimensional array with the outer arrays key being the date, and the inner array being the rows.  That way it would naturally sort them out.  But it would be easier to do `ORDER BY`...

Comment: performance wise you cant compare the date with a time component,  So you would either have to change it like is being done, or if its a query with a datetime field you can do this `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_on,'%d-%b-%Y) as create_date,  DATE_FORMAT(created_on,'%h:%i %p) as created_time...`  Please note it looks like the OP has the wrong date format for what the output says :-p  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is hold last date in a temp variable and compare it with current date of iteration:

```
<?php if (!empty($notification)):
$date = ''; ?>
<table class="table" id="notification_table">
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($notification as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>
            <?php if($date != $row['created_on']){
                echo date('d M',strtotime($row['created_on']));
                $date = $row['created_on'];
            } ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['notification_text'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">No notification</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: This is the same logic i mention in the comment. This is good also.

Comment: i did your suggestion, but it gives me the same result, i mean the same date still echoing

Comment: This will compare the current date only to the last one, if dates are not sorted than it will not works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in this way

```
          <tbody>
               <!-- define $previous_value variable here to keep tmp value -->
                <?php $previous_value = ""; ?>
                <?php foreach ($notification as $row): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td nowrap>
                            <?php 
                            if($previous_value != $row['created_on']){
                            echo date('d M',strtotime($row['created_on']));
                            }
                            $previous_value = $row['created_on'];
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo date('h:m A', strtotime($row['created_on'])) ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $row['notification_text'] ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help in case that dates are not sorted in the input array as shown in this exapmle:

```
<?php
$notification=array(0=>array('created_on'=> '18-sept-2016 08:00 AM','notification_text'=>'some text1'),
                    1=>array('created_on'=> '19-sept-2016 09:10 AM','notification_text'=>'some text2'),
                    2=>array('created_on'=> '19-sept-2016 09:00 AM','notification_text'=>'some text3'),
                    3=>array('created_on'=> '18-sept-2016 11:00 AM','notification_text'=>'some text4'),
                    4=>array('created_on'=> '19-sept-2016 12:00 AM','notification_text'=>'some text5'));

$new_array=array();
foreach($notification as $index => $value){
     $item=array();
     $item['time']=date('h:m A', strtotime($value['created_on'])); 
     $item['text']=$value['notification_text'];
     $new_array[date('d M',strtotime($value['created_on']))][]=$item;
}
?>
<?php if (!empty($new_array)): ?>
            <table class="table" id="notification_table">
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($new_array as $index=>$row): ?>
                        <?php foreach ($row as $index_item=>$row_item): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td nowrap>
                                <?php if($index_item ==0) echo $index ?>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row_item['time'] ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $row_item['text'] ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                          <?php endforeach ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    No notification
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
```